# How to disable auto "Update Maven Dependencies" after saving a pom.xml?

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

How to disable auto "Update Maven Dependencies" after saving a `pom.xml` in Eclipse IDE with m2eclipse Plugin?

```
16.04.10 11:09:40 MESZ: Refreshing [/project/pom.xml]
16.04.10 11:09:40 MESZ: Maven Builder: AUTO_BUILD
```

Comment: I would suggest disabling auto building `Project -> Build Automatically`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. But why would you even want to do that? Keeping your project build path in sync with the pom is a good thing.

Comment: It extremely slows down my eclipse and often completely blocks the UI, as i also prefer to disable "Build All" in Eclipse, i prefer to update at the time i want.

Comment: @chrsk 1. What version of m2eclipse are you using? I noticed a big improvement with version 0.10.0. 2. Do you changes versions that often? 3. m2eclipse is maybe not for you then, maybe consider switching to the maven-eclipse-plugin.

Comment: Having the same problem. Maven is making Eclipse very sluggish and a manual update would be nice. But then I probably need to change the PC :)

Answer (score 17):

Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> enable Offline option

Answer (score 1):

You can edit "Goals to run when updating project configuration" in Window > Preferences > Maven.
Default setting is "process-resources", try to remove it.

Comment: This results also in `AUTO BUILD`.

Comment: Do You really need m2plugin? I prefer maven-eclipse-plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If you disable "process-resources" in a Spring application, you will not get any resource files such as log4j.xml or Spring configuration files copied to the