# Maven continuously building EAR module for Java EE project

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

I have a Maven Java EE project built using [javaee5-maven-archetype](http://code.google.com/p/javaee5-maven-archetype/) and imported into Eclipse(Helios). The EAR module of the project is continuolsy build every second, even when there are no changes. Sometime Eclipse freezes and i have to kill the process. Nothing is listed in the Problems view but the below is displayed continuosly on the Maven Console.

```
2010/10/04 12:05:27 PM: Refreshing [/MyProject-ear/pom.xml]
2010/10/04 12:05:27 PM: Refreshing [/MyProject-ear/pom.xml]
2010/10/04 12:05:28 PM: Maven Builder: AUTO_BUILD 
2010/10/04 12:05:28 PM: Maven Builder: AUTO_BUILD 
2010/10/04 12:05:28 PM: Maven Builder: AUTO_BUILD 
2010/10/04 12:05:28 PM: Refreshing [/MyProject-ear/pom.xml]
2010/10/04 12:05:28 PM: Refreshing [/MyProject-ear/pom.xml]
2010/10/04 12:05:29 PM: Maven Builder: AUTO_BUILD 
2010/10/04 12:05:29 PM: Maven Builder: AUTO_BUILD 
2010/10/04 12:05:29 PM: Maven Builder: AUTO_BUILD 
2010/10/04 12:05:29 PM: Refreshing [/MyProject-ear/pom.xml]
2010/10/04 12:05:30 PM: Refreshing [/MyProject-ear/pom.xml]
2010/10/04 12:05:30 PM: Maven Builder: AUTO_BUILD 
2010/10/04 12:05:30 PM: Maven Builder: AUTO_BUILD
```

I'm using [M2Eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/)

Comment: is this related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651694/how-to-disable-auto-update-maven-dependencies-after-saving-a-pom-xml ?

Comment: No, they are not related, I prefer having AUTO_BUILD, it (m2eclipse) just shouldn't build every second when there are no changes to the pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reinstalled m2e WITHOUT the m2e extras

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem until I unchecked "skip maven compiler plugin when processing resources" in Project properties/Maven/Lifecycle mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work for you, but check the Builders list in the Project properties (Project->Properties->Builders), the Maven Project Builder is listed there, maybe if you disable this builder (I haven't tried) you could get rid of that problem.

Best regards.